# How to monitor CPU usage on an application instead of individual processes?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I'd like to track the CPU and memory usage of an app - e.g. Brave or Chrome - which, if you check with a tool such as htop or System Monitor, shows a large number of separate processes (as below).

[image: ![Multiple brave processes showing CPU and memory columns]

How could I track the grouped/summed CPU and memory usage of the entire application instead of these individual processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post
[Sum the memory usages of all the processes of a program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209689/sum-the-memory-usages-of-all-the-processes-of-a-program)
has suggestions for utilities that also do CPU in addition to memory:

- Use [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/). Type <kbd>P</kbd> to see *per program* statistics:

  ```
                                                                       PAUSED
  NPROCS  SYSCPU  USRCPU   VSIZE  RSIZE   RDDSK  WRDSK  SNET  MEM CMD         1/4
      17   1.14s   8.06s   14.3G   2.7G       ?      ?     ?  35% chrome
       1   0.30s   0.30s    2.6G   1.9G       ?      ?     ?  25% Xorg
       1   0.09s   1.15s    1.8G 329.7M       ?      ?     ?   4% gnome-shell
       1   0.00s   0.07s  994.8M 257.2M       ?      ?     ?   3% thunderbird
       1   0.00s   0.00s    1.3G 162.4M       ?      ?     ?   2% soffice.bin
       2   0.00s   0.00s    1.2G 86736K       ?      ?     ?   1% gvim
       1   0.00s   0.01s    1.0G 64724K       ?      ?     ?   1% owncloud
       1   0.00s   0.00s  970.3M 59908K       ?      ?     ?   1% evolution-cale
       1   0.00s   0.00s  675.7M 48404K       ?      ?     ?   1% tracker-extrac
       1   0.03s   0.03s  581.0M 47080K       ?      ?     ?   1% xchat
       2   0.00s   0.00s   84.2G 45292K       ?      ?     ?   1% nacl_helper
  ```
- Use the `ps` command with `awk`:

  ```
  ps -eo size,command --sort -pcpu | grep chromium | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; sum +=hr} END {print sum}'
  ```

  For repeated use, create an executable file, here named `cpusum` containing :

  ```
  ps -eo size,command --sort -pcpu | grep $1 | awk '{ hr=$1/1024 ; sum +=hr; echo $1} END {print sum}'
  #                                       ^this $1 will come from runtime argument
  ```

  Make it executable:

  ```
  chmod +x cpusum
  ```

  And to use:

  ```
  ./cpusum chromium
  ```
- Use [qps - Visual Process Manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/qps.1.html):

  [image]

Answer (score -1):

You can execut this command:

```
  ps -p <pid> -o %cpu,%mem,cmd
```

Or another example of this command is that retourns de cpu, mem, and tipe of bash usage.

[image]

Look this link https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html

for example in the following image I am using the top command of a lifetime.

In the %Cpu section you can see where it says "num" us. This indicates the workload of the cpu approximately.

[image]

Comment: How would that show a sum of multiple processes?

Comment: Your first example will track a *single process*. The second shows the *entire cpu*. I am interested in all the processes spawned by the "Brave browser" app, which means multiple processes but not the entire CPU.